# IndexError: in the future, 0-d boolean arrays will be interpreted as a valid boolean index

Tags: python, list, numpy, matplotlib, tuples

So I am trying to read a list from file and then plot it as a graph.

Here is My Code

```
with open('the list') as f:
     listoflang = [tuple(map( str ,i.split())) for i in f]
print listoflang 

import numpy as np                                                               
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt  

top= listoflang

labels, ys = zip(*top)
xs = np.arange(len(labels)) 
width = 1

fig = plt.figure()                                                               
ax = fig.gca()
ax.bar(xs, ys, width, align='center')
ax.set_xticks(xs)
ax.set_xticklabels(labels)
ax.set_yticks(ys)

plt.savefig('graph.png')
```

The listoflang looks like this

[('mysql', 2), ('unix', 2), ('linux', 1), ('perl', 2), ('php', 4), ('java', 25), ('javascript(beginner)', 1), ('ruby', 2), ('html', 9), ('android', 1), ('css', 4), ('shell', 1), ('c/c++', 1), ('python', 29), ('javascript', 3), ('c#(beginner)', 1), ('jsp', 1), ('sql', 2), ('html&css', 1), ('c', 37), ('python(basics', 1), ('c++', 25), ('cpp', 5)]

But this return this

```
> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "graphmon.py", line 22, in
> <module>
>     plt.savefig('graph.png')   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/matplotlib/pyplot.py", line
> 697, in savefig
>     res = fig.savefig(*args, **kwargs)   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/matplotlib/figure.py", line
> 1573, in savefig
>     self.canvas.print_figure(*args, **kwargs)   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/matplotlib/backend_bases.py",
> line 2252, in print_figure
>     **kwargs)   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/matplotlib/backends/backend_agg.py",
> line 545, in print_png
>     FigureCanvasAgg.draw(self)   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/matplotlib/backends/backend_agg.py",
> line 464, in draw
>     self.figure.draw(self.renderer)   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/matplotlib/artist.py", line
> 63, in draw_wrapper
>     draw(artist, renderer, *args, **kwargs)   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/matplotlib/figure.py", line
> 1144, in draw
>     renderer, self, dsu, self.suppressComposite)   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/matplotlib/image.py", line
> 139, in _draw_list_compositing_images
>     a.draw(renderer)   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/matplotlib/artist.py", line
> 63, in draw_wrapper
>     draw(artist, renderer, *args, **kwargs)   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/matplotlib/axes/_base.py",
> line 2426, in draw
>     mimage._draw_list_compositing_images(renderer, self, dsu)   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/matplotlib/image.py", line
> 139, in _draw_list_compositing_images
>     a.draw(renderer)   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/matplotlib/artist.py", line
> 63, in draw_wrapper
>     draw(artist, renderer, *args, **kwargs)   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/matplotlib/axis.py", line
> 1136, in draw
>     ticks_to_draw = self._update_ticks(renderer)   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/matplotlib/axis.py", line 969,
> in _update_ticks
>     tick_tups = [t for t in self.iter_ticks()]   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/matplotlib/axis.py", line 914,
> in iter_ticks
>     self.major.formatter.set_locs(majorLocs)   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/matplotlib/ticker.py", line
> 644, in set_locs
>     self._compute_offset()   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/matplotlib/ticker.py", line
> 656, in _compute_offset
>     locs = locs[(vmin <= locs) & (locs <= vmax)] IndexError: in the future, 0-d boolean arrays will be interpreted as a valid boolean
> index
```

What Might I be doing wrong?
Thanks in advance!!

Comment: Can you please include the traceback?

Comment: Your code runs fine if I set `top = [the values you posted for listoflang]` (on python 3.6). Which version of python are you using?

Comment: Version Python 2.7.13 . Is there any way around this though?

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/AKzjA.png @roganjosh

Comment: I cannot replicate this on Python 2.7.13 (Anaconda) with mpl version 2.0.2. I have no idea what it's complaining about tbh... It seems to be its own source code throwing the error

Comment: That really looks like an error deep inside matplotlib.

Comment: Yep. I suggest updating matplotlib, I don't think you can fix this any other way.

Comment: updated the library. Issue still persisit

Answer (score -1):

I have a similar issue with constructs using numpy arrays and masks on Python 3.5.2 and numpy 1.12.1 .

Construct where the error shows up:
`ret[ix,(mask==zeroes)] = 0`

where mask has dimensions complementary to the 1st dimension of ret, and mask and zeroes are binary arrays (only zeros and ones inside) with the same dimension.

When the warnings filter is configured to generate errors

```
with warnings.catch_warnings():
warnings.simplefilter("error")  # "ignore" if not solved quickly
```

ret[ix,(mask==zeroes)] = 0

When the warnings filter is configured to generate errors, I get more frequently
the issue. When the filter is set on "warn", the error message changes as well.

```
with warnings.catch_warnings():
warnings.simplefilter("error")  # "ignore" if not solved quickly

ret[ix,(mask==zeroes)] = 0
```

I am not sure what the correct workaround would be.